# Custom ViewPager giving an exception

Tags: android, exception, android-viewpager

I am trying to add a custom `ViewPager` for enabling/disabling swipe feature but i have been getting errors. I have implemented custom_viewpager in a separate class and extended the `ViewPager`.

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <com.example.sumit.myapplication.custom_viewpager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/pager_threee"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The related JAVA code is:

```
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

ViewPager vp;
private static double latitude = 0.0;
private static double longitude = 0.0;
private static String Country = "";
private static String Locality = "";
private static String AreaCode = "";
private static String My_Id = "0";

List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
Fragment frag_public_list;
Fragment frag_users_list;
Fragment frag_profile;
Fragment frag_photos;
adapter _adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main__users__page);

    frag_users_list = new users_list();

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putDouble("lat", latitude);
    bundle.putDouble("long", longitude);
    bundle.putString("Country", Country);
    bundle.putString("Locality", Locality);
    bundle.putString("AreaCode", AreaCode);
    bundle.putString("My_Id", My_Id);

    frag_users_list.setArguments(bundle);
    frag_public_list = new public_chat();

    fragments.add(frag_public_list);
    fragments.add(frag_users_list);

    vp = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager_threee);
```

The exception I have been getting is:

```
Java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sumit.myapplication/com.example.sumit.myapplication.Main_Users_Page}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class com.example.sumit.myapplion.custom_viewpager
```

The custom_viewpager class is:

```java
package com.example.sumit.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

/**
 * Created by Sumit on 7/27/2015.
 */
public class custom_viewpager extends ViewPager {

    private boolean enabled;

    public custom_viewpager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.enabled) {
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.enabled) {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void setPagingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }
}
```

Comment: The error seems to be with your `custom_viewpager` class, so you'll have to include that code as well.

Comment: Ok,,, I have now added the custom_viewpager class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add the following constructors for your `custom_viewpager` class to be inflated correctly:

```
public custom_viewpager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public custom_viewpager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}
```

Comment: Also for the titlestrip.. do I just extend the com.package.custom_adapter.PagerTitleStrip?

Comment: @SumitBahadur You're better off asking that in a new question, as I'm not sure of the answer. Mark this answer as accepted and create a new question.